# easy_install creates an egg directory instead of egg file

Tags: python, easy-install, egg

I ran 'easy_install .' for one of my packages, in hopes of creating an egg file to use elsewhere. It successfully installs the package; however, instead of creating an egg file in my /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages directory, it creates a directory there called my_package.egg, which contains two directories: EGG-INFO, and another named after my package containing the source code (.py and .pyc files).

I have another similar package, which "successfully" creates the desired .egg file when easy_install is run, and I don't know what's different about the packages and why easy_install produces different results.

I couldn't find any documentation about .egg directories (rather than files) and why they're created. I'd like to know how to remedy this to get a .egg file.

Answer (score 0):

Use `zip_safe=True` in your `setup()`:

```py
setup(
    name='your_project',
    version='0.1',
    packages=find_packages(exclude=['tests']),
    zip_safe=True
)
```